# Cursor jumps to end of field if you attempt to edit

Tags: javascript, html, css, safari

This only happens in Safari.  I have a simple text field that is used for email.  If you enter some text, then move the cursor over a few spaces to edit and enter more, as soon as you start typing it puts the cursor at the end and puts the new characters there.  It appears to be this bit of code causing the problem.

```js
function clearErrors() {
  var authError = document.getElementById("authError");
  var error = document.getElementById("error");

  if (authError !== null) {
    document.getElementById("authError").innerHTML = "";
  }

  if (error !== null) {
    document.getElementById("error").innerHTML = "";
  }


  function postOnReturn(e) {
    document.forms[0]['pf.username'].value = document.forms[0]
      ['pf.username'].value.trim();
    var keycode;

    if (window.event) keycode = window.event.keyCode;
    else if (e) keycode = e.which;
    else return true;

    if (keycode == 13) {
      if ($isCustomerInternal == 'false')
        if ($("#username").val().indexOf("@") === -1) {
          document.querySelector('.emailError').style.display = 'block';
          return;
        }
      else if ($("#username").val().indexOf("@") !== -1) {
        document.querySelector('.emailError').style.display = 'none';
      }
      end
      disableFields();
      document.forms[0].submit();
      return false;
    } else {
      return true;
    }
  }
```

```html
<input id="username" name="pf.username" type="text" class="form-control 
    card-input" value="$username" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" onKeyPress="clearErrors();return postOnReturn(event)" autofocus>
```

Comment: That code by itself will _not_ do what you describe. There is more happening here. Can you show us where and how this is called and what other events / listeners you have in your script? Ideally, this should be in the form of a Minimal, Complete, Verifiable [Example]((https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)).

Comment: Where is this piece of code called from? Can you provide a working example?

Comment: @ShaneP did you ever fix this error? If so, what was the solution?

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few syntax errors in your code, mainly missing opening/closing brackets in if statements. Also one of your functions was missing a closing bracket. You can use a syntax-checker online to double check your js syntax in future if you are unsure about js syntax.

On 'return'/enter-press in this snippet, there is a brief message of an uncaught reference, because there was no '.emailError' code shared. This would resolve this. If your code was correct, the issue you described would probably be resolved. Without more code I was unable to reproduce your issue, but I hope this helps.

```js
function clearErrors() {
  var authError = document.getElementById("authError");
  var error = document.getElementById("error");

  if (authError !== null) {
    document.getElementById("authError").innerHTML = "";
  }

  if (error !== null) {
    document.getElementById("error").innerHTML = "";
  }
}

function postOnReturn(e) {
  var keycode;
  document.forms[0]['pf.username'].value = document.forms[0]
    ['pf.username'].value.trim();


  if (window.event) {
    keycode = window.event.keyCode;
  } else if (e) {
    keycode = e.which;
  } else {
    return true;
  }

  if (keycode == 13) {
    if ($isCustomerInternal == 'false') {
      if ($("#username").val().indexOf("@") === -1) {
        document.querySelector('.emailError').style.display = 'block';
        return;
      }
    } else if ($("#username").val().indexOf("@") !== -1) {
      document.querySelector('.emailError').style.display = 'none';
      end
      disableFields();
      document.forms[0].submit();
      return false;
    } else {
      return true;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input id="username" name="pf.username" type="text" class="form-control 
    card-input" value="$username" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" onKeyPress="clearErrors();return postOnReturn(event)" autofocus>
</form>
```